# Python AWS IoT Core: Create thingName shadow

Tags: python, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

In the AWS Documentation, there are only instructions on how to update_thing_shadow. (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot-data.html#IoTDataPlane.Client.update_thing_shadow)

How do we create the thing shadow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just tried update_thing_shadow to create the shadow and it works.